# Is web3j safe to use?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

web3j is lightweight and to achieve so it heavily relies on a single selected client (full node) to access the ethereum network. I seems like there is too much trust on this single selected full node, all access has to go through it. What happen if this node is compromised. How will the web3j end find out or any protection against it?

Comment: If you don't want to trust a public node (like Infura), you can run your own node.

Comment: If i were to use ethereum to develop a commercial product that will destroy the purpose of server-less if I have to host a full node

Comment: By default, people tend to point to a public node like Infura. But users should be able to whatever node they like.

Comment: so i have to keep a lookout for trusted node

Comment: Sorry, left out a word: "should be able to _use_ whatever node they like"